# Which of the listed import statements are identical?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, require

I have identified the following import statements in *node*. Do all the statements below import `mathgraph` with a different namespace scope, or which import styles are identical?

```js
const/var/let mathgraph = require('mathgraph');

import * as mathgraph from 'mathgraph';
import mathgraph from 'mathgraph';
import { mathgraph } from 'mathgraph';
import mathgraph = require('mathgraph');
```

Comment: This `import mathgraph = require('mathgraph');` isn't legal syntax.  Did you mean `const mathgraph = require('mathgraph');`?

Comment: @jfriend00 It is a custom module from our institute, and i am supposed to import it via `import mathgraph from 'mathgraph'` but I didn't know the real difference between this and the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// mathgrab lib
export default { foo: 'foo' }

// your code
import mathgraph from 'mathgraph';
mathgrab.foo
```

This imports the *default* export.

---

```
// mathgrab lib
export const someObject = { foo: 'foo' }

// your code
import { someObject } from 'mathgraph';
someObject.foo
```

This imports a *named* export.

---

```
// mathgrab lib
export const someObject = { foo: 'foo' }
export default { bar: 'bar' }

// your code
import mathgraph, { someObject } from 'mathgraph';
mathgrab.someObject.foo
mathgrab.default.bar
```

You can even combine these two to import both kinds of exports in one line.

---

```
// mathgrab lib
export const someObject = { foo: 'foo' }
export default { bar: 'bar' }

// your code
import * as mathgraph from 'mathgraph';
mathgrab.someObject.foo
mathgrab.default.bar
```

This imports *all* exports as a single object. The `default` export will be on the `default` property of this object.

---

```
const mathgraph = require('mathgraph');
```

This only works in node, and is functionally the same as `import *`, but it's a dynamic runtime require, rather than than a compile time import. That means that typescript can't use the types of the imported file. `require` is *just* a function, so it returns a value of type `any`, thereby missing out on all typing info.

Don't use `require` with typescript, you pretty always want to use `import` instead.

---

```
import mathgraph = require('mathgraph');
```

And lastly, this is invalid syntax. So don't do that.

Comment: What a gem of an answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding the invalid syntax. I remember where I got it from. See https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-var-requires.md#-correct

Comment: Hmm, it appears that syntax is only allowed when targeting CommonJS modules, I think. I'm guessing that this does the same thing as `const foo = require('foo')` but maybe typescript can get some static types from it? Not really sure. I wouldn't use it for anything modern, though. `import/from` is the way forward.